# Proof of stable manifold theorem using a lemma

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a general system $x'=Ax + h(x)$. The statement goes as such: prove the stable manifold theorem using the following result.

> Consider the hypothesis of the stable manifold theorem. Then, there exist $r_1$, $r_2$ such that $r_1 < r_2$ and a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^k \cap B_{r_1}(0)\to\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ such that
>
> - $\phi(0) = \phi'(0) = 0$,
> - $\phi$ is $C^1$ on a neighbourhood of $0$,
> - if $x_0 = (y_0, z_0)$ with $|y_0|<r_1$, then the problem $x'=Ax+h(x)$, $x(0)=x_0$ admits a solution $x(t,x_0)$ which verifies $|x(t,x_0)|\leq r_2$ iff $z_0 = \phi(y_0)$,
> - if $z_0 = \phi(y_0)$ then $\limsup_{t\to +\infty} \frac{\log |x(t,x_0)|}{t} \leq \alpha$.

The only reference I found about something like this (i.e. similar statements) is Coddington and Levinson, and even that didn't help much. Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed?